# Order array. undefined method `order' for Array. Convert array into hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, hash

I have a City model and in city's show action I want to render hotels nearby specific locations in the city. Cities has_many locations; hotels are being searched using Geocoder near method.

To add order functionality I've followed Ryan Bates [screencasts #228](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns), but this approach doesn't seem to work with arrays, giving error `` undefined method `order' for #< Array:0x007f960d003430> ``

```
cities_controller.rb

helper_method :sort_column, :sort_direction
def show
  session[:search_radius] = 2 if session[:search_radius].blank?
  @city = City.find(params[:id])
  @locations = @city.locations
  @hotels = []
  @locations.each do |location|
    unless location.longitude.blank? || location.latitude.blank? 
      center_point = [location.latitude, location.longitude]
      box = Geocoder::Calculations.bounding_box(center_point, session[:search_radius])
      thotels = Hotel.near(center_point, session[:search_radius]).within_bounding_box(box)
    else
      thotels = Hotel.near(center_point, session[:search_radius])
    end
    @hotels += thotels if thotels
    @hotels = @hotels.uniq
  end
  @hotels = @hotels.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
  @json = @locations.to_gmaps4rails

  respond_with @json, :location => city_url
end


private

  def sort_column
    Hotel.column_names.include?(params[:sort]) ? params[:sort] : "name"
  end

  def sort_direction
    %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
  end
```

My question is: should I concentrate in converting an array into hash or should I initially create hash of hotels, or maybe find completely different approach to perform sorting?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`order` is a method used for sorting at the database level.  since `@hotels` is an array, you won't be able to sort using `order`.  Try the following (not tested and you may want to include array pagination if you haven't included it yet)

```
@hotels = @hotels.sort_by(&:"#{sort_column}")
@hotels = @hotels.reverse if sort_direction == 'DESC'
@hotels = @hotels.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5)
```