# Sorting 2 arrays that have been added together

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

In my app, users can create galleries that their work may or may not be in.  Users have and belong to many Galleries, and each gallery has a 'creator' that is designated by the gallery's `user_id` field.

So to get the 5 latest galleries a user is in, I can do something like:

```
included_in = @user.galleries.order('created_at DESC').uniq.first(5)
# SELECT DISTINCT "galleries".* FROM "galleries" INNER JOIN "galleries_users" ON "galleries"."id" = "galleries_users"."gallery_id" WHERE "galleries_users"."user_id" = 10 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5
```

and to get the 5 latest galleries they've created, I can do:

```
created = Gallery.where(user_id: id).order('created_at DESC').uniq.first(5)
# SELECT DISTINCT "galleries".* FROM "galleries" WHERE "galleries"."user_id" = 10 ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 5
```

I want to display these two together, so that it's the 5 latest galleries that they've created OR they're in.  Something like the equivalent of:

```
(included_in + created).order('created_at DESC').uniq.first(5)
```

Does anyone know how to construct an efficient query or post-query loop that does this?

Comment: does `(included_in + created).order('created_at DESC').uniq.first(5)` not work?  or is it a matter of trying to make fewer queries?

Comment: @dax it doesn't work, gives `undefined method 'order' for #<Array:0x007fda568e8248>`

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/15731483/2128691

Comment: @dax works beautifully, thanks!  I'm happy to award the answer too, if you want to write up the solution: `(included_in + created).sort_by(&:created_at).uniq.first(5)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`order` isn't available, but you can use `sort` - or `sort_by` as suggested by [jvnill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337166/jvnill) in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731483/2128691)

As you've stated, you can use the following code:

```
(included_in + created).sort_by(&:created_at).uniq.first(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
Gallery.joins("LEFT JOIN galleries_users ON galleries.id = galleries_users.gallery_id")
  .where("galleries_users.user_id = :user_id OR galleries.user_id = :user_id", user_id: id)
  .order("galleries.created_at DESC")
  .limit(5)
```

I'm assuming the name of your HABTM join table is galleries_users (which is the default).

Comment: Thanks @sampierson, this may work but I was hoping to keep it simple/readable/Rails-y rather than use a dedicated SQL query if possible

Answer (score -1):

Union the two queries and select the order from the union.

Comment: That's a pretty general statement... care to elaborate?