# Rails: Sort_by :created_by - array with multiple classes

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array of two completely different classes, '`Article`' and '`Comment`' in a method in my `User` model. I'm trying to order all of these by a descending `created_at` order. So far, the best I've been able to achieve is getting the objects in one class of the array in descending order, then the other class objects to follow it in descending order. I'd like to have all of these objects integrated in order by `created_at`, not ordered separately.

I've been browsing, and I've come across a few 'supposed' solutions, none of which are elegant. Here's an example that I tried- ([Order array. undefined method `order' for Array. Convert array into hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730432/order-array-undefined-method-order-for-array-convert-array-into-hash)) --

```
def follow_feed
    objects = Article.from_followed_users(self) + Comment.from_followed_users(self)
    objects = objects.sort_by(&:created_at)
    objects = objects.reverse if sort_direction == 'DESC'
end
```

Then defining this - (from the link) -

```
def sort_direction
  %w[asc desc].include?(params[:direction]) ? params[:direction] : "asc"
end
```

The `from_followed_users(self)` are scopes defined in their respective classes. There's got to be a simple, working solution that I haven't found yet. Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Thanks. Updated. Is there not a simple method of doing this, that you know off the top of your head?

Comment: The current solution is the "simple" solution as far as I know. It's not necessarily the "most efficient" solution (in particular it won't leverage database indices) but, for only a little bit of fetched data, or for a result-set that is entirely materialized anyway, it should be "efficient enough".