# Ruby - Re-assign values to attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a belong_to/has_many relation between Deal and Step :

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_many   :steps,          dependent:  :destroy do   
    def length
      reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).length
    end
  end 

accepts_nested_attributes_for :steps, allow_destroy: true

end
```

Step belongs to Deal and has an attribute called step_rank.

I would like to find a method to take all Steps and change the values of their step_ranks so that:

- the lowest initial step_rank value gets a value of 0
- the others , **while keeping the same "order" in terms of initial step_rank** , simply make up at the end a series with +1 increments

Let me give you an example if we have the following Steps fora given Deal (id:5 for example) initially:

```
Deal(id=5).step(id:1).step_rank = 15
Deal(id=5).step(id:4).step_rank = 4
Deal(id=5).step(id:7).step_rank = 9
Deal(id=5).step(id:37).step_rank = 30
```

then I need to find a way to transform those attribute's values into:

```
Deal(id=5).step(id:1).step_rank = 2
Deal(id=5).step(id:4).step_rank = 0
Deal(id=5).step(id:7).step_rank = 1
Deal(id=5).step(id:37).step_rank = 3
```

As you see the final values make a up a series of values starting at 0 and incrementing one by one while keeping the initial order.

I found a way to re-order them **but not really to change each of their values**. How to do it?

model/deal.rb

```
implement_increment( self.steps.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).map{|u| u.step_rank} )

def implement_increment(array)
  sorted = array.sort
  lastNum = sorted[0]
  sorted[1, sorted.count].each do |n|
    lastNum = n
  end
  true
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Deal.find(5).steps.order(:step_rank).each_with_index do |step, index|
  step.update_attributes step_rank: index
end
```

Comment: id 5 was just an example I'll try with self.steps.order(:step_rank).each_with_index do |step, index|
  step.update_attributes step_rank: index
end

Comment: I get error: undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x00000004edf428>

Comment: Considering your case `Deal#steps` should be a relation rather than an array. And a relation has method `order`

Comment: I agree but i don't know why it's an array... in models/Deal.rb , I can't say of course only "do this for id=5" (id 5 was given to clarify an example), so I use the broader approach : self.steps.reject(&:marked_for_destruction?).order(:step_rank).each_with_index do |step, index|
          step.update_attributes step_rank: index
        end
      end

Comment: I got what you mean about `Deal.find(5)`. It's just an example also. What is context for self by the way?

Comment: well self is the Deal itself as i write self inside a method of the file models/deal.rb. self.steps go to fetch the steps associated with the present Deal.

Comment: Maybe you override steps method somewhere in your Deal model

Comment: This is super weird: If I put in the method a "puts self.steps" to see how it prints in the console I see: #<Step:0x007fa357d52940>
#<Step:0x007fa357d52670>
#<Step:0x007fa357d523a0>
#<Step:0x007fa357d520f8>
#<Step:0x007fa357d51dd8>
#<Step:0x007fa357d51b30>
#<Step:0x007fa357d51860>
#<Step:0x007fa357d51540>
#<Step:0x007fa357d51298>
#<Step:0x007fa357d50ed8>
#<Step:0x007fa357d50500>. so self.steps is not an array...So why do I get the error undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x007fa32c355af8> hahah

Comment: found the reasons: As stated in this other SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730432/order-array-undefined-method-order-for-array-convert-array-into-hash, "order is a method used for sorting at the database level. since @hotels is an array, you won't be able to sort using order". Replacing it with sort_by(&:step_rank) make it work. Thanks for your help!